# Javascript Fetch: How to fix downloaded blob with weird background colours?

Tags: blob, fetch, aurelia

I regularly download images as blob and show them in the html or download the to the HD. Most of the time they show correctly. But sometimes they are loaded for 50% or with weird background colours. Like these examples (last one is normal).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is how I download the images. I use the `aurelia-fetch-client` in the aurelia framework for this.

Html:

```
<div css="background-image: url(${ imageUrl })"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const blob = await this.client.fetch(`${this.endpoint}/attachments/${this.attachment.name}`,
    {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((x) => x.blob());
this.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Any idea what is causing this? It happens randomly to images that I show in the webbrowser or download to the HD. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you the images are not curropted? is the same images sometimes work and somtimes don't?

Comment: Images are not corrupt. When I refresh the page, the picture that has a weird background shows normally after the refresh.

Comment: Interesting. Couple of days ago I faced a similar issue (downloading file though) and fixed it by adding another promise return. For your case like so: `.then((x) => x.blob()).then((blob) =>{this.imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);});` Due to time constraints I've put it on a pile of questions I`d like to ask on SO on another day.